# Changing fonts on a per encoding or per file basis in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, encoding, fonts, ide

Is there a way to change the font used by the editor in Eclipse on a per file or per encoding basis?

For example:

- There's a resource file that has glyphs not supported by certain Unicode fonts, and I would like, for this particular file, to use a different font, or
- I set the encoding for a resource file to be one that which the default font does not support. I would like to open these files using a font that actually supports the encoding.

Is there any way to configure something like this in Eclipse? I somehow remember Eclipse changing the font when the default font doesn't support the file's encoding, but that doesn't seem to be happening anymore.